# numpy.loadtxt does not read file with complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a file with complex numbers in the form :

```
data.dat

1.5795219122457646E-11-3.852906516379872E-15i   -3.5949335665378405E-12-1.626143709108086E-15i
-6.720365121161621E-15-5.377186331212649E-17i   -3.736251476362349E-15-3.0190920417856674E-17i
```

I use the following code to read the file :

```
import numpy as np

c_complex = np.loadtxt('data.dat', delimiter='\t', dtype=np.complex128)
```

But it gives me the following error :

```
TypeError: complex() argument must be a string or a number, not 'bytes'
```

What could I do to solve this problem ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you are using Python 3?

Comment: In which case this may be a bug in `numpy`, though I can't imagine something so basic going untested. The issue is, in Python 3 one can't pass a bytestring to `complex()` because text is no longer represented by bytestrings. It looks as though the file is being opened in binary mode by `loadtxt()`.

Comment: Yes Python 3.4.3 and numpy 1.9.2

Comment: If I use Python 2 the error is : ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to have been a bug in older versions of numpy ([Issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5655)). Either update your numpy to the latest version of their github repository or use the function numpy.genfromtxt().

```
c.complex = np.genfromtxt('data.dat', delimiter='\t', dtype=np.complex128)
```

Comment: c_complex , not c.complex which will throw an error